# Expo Fingerprint API not working properly in Android devices.

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to implement finger-print scan functionality in `react-native` app and using the code below. It is working fine in iOS device but when I try the same code in any android device, Its stops scanning if on failure. My aim is to make the device scan until it receives correct finger print.

```
scanBiometrics = async () => {
    let result = await Expo.Fingerprint.authenticateAsync('Biometric Scan.');
    if (result.success) {
      // code
      );
    } else {
      //code
    }
  };
```